# SQL: Converting a Sub-query to a Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am learning SQL in a course, and I'm working with SQL on MS SQL Server (so, T-SQL). I'm trying to re-factor a sub-query using a common table expression (CTE). Here's the working sub-query version:

```
SELECT  PAT_ENC_CSN_ID 'CSN',
        ADMISSION_PROV_ID 'Provider ID'

FROM PAT_ENC_HSP

WHERE ADMISSION_PROV_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PROV_ID
    FROM CL_SER_HIM_LST_VST
    WHERE HIM_STATUS_C <> 1001
    )
```

I had thought that a CTE was (nearly) a drop-in replacement, so I attempted the following:

```
WITH Not_Good AS (  SELECT DISTINCT PROV_ID
                    FROM CL_SER_HIM_LST_VST
                    WHERE HIM_STATUS_C <> 1001
                 )

SELECT  PAT_ENC_CSN_ID 'CSN',
        ADMISSION_PROV_ID 'Provider ID'

FROM PAT_ENC_HSP

WHERE PAT_ENC_HSP.ADMISSION_PROV_ID IN (Not_Good.PROV_ID)
```

But I'm getting a syntax error in the final `WHERE` clause: `The multi-part identifier "Not_Good.PROV_ID" could not be bound.`

> What is the issue, here?

I don't have any `JOIN`'s with a missing `ON` condition, nor do I see an alias missing.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Why do you need to make it multi-part?

Comment: This is for a course, so it's an exercise.

Comment: Tip: You can replace the final `select` in the CTE version with `select * from Not_Good;` to debug that part of the query. As your CTEs get more complicated and have multiple queries built atop one another it's a handy way to check the intermediate results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close, but you can't use the CTE in the 'IN' statement in the way you listed above. You can do this, though:

```
WITH Not_Good AS (  SELECT DISTINCT PROV_ID
                    FROM CL_SER_HIM_LST_VST
                    WHERE HIM_STATUS_C <> 1001
                 )

SELECT  PAT_ENC_CSN_ID 'CSN',
        ADMISSION_PROV_ID 'Provider ID'

FROM PAT_ENC_HSP

WHERE PAT_ENC_HSP.ADMISSION_PROV_ID IN (select PROV_ID from Not_Good)
```

Comment: Ah, I see now my book says, "In other (meaning, not `FROM` clauses) clauses, CTEs must be in the `FROM` clause of a sub-query which in turn must be enclosed in parentheses. This is often as simple as `(SELECT * FROM cte)`." If only I'd read a little more carefully!

Comment: A `WHERE EXISTS` would probably be better. Or an `INNER JOIN` (but deal with dupes if necessary).